# How do I get the return value from a meteor method call?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor method defined on the client side using the pattern described here https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#advanced-boilerplate

```
// files.collection.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export const mediaFiles = new Mongo.Collection('media_files')

export const method_InsertFile = {
    name: 'media_file.insert',

    // Factor out validation so that it can be run independently (1)
    validate(args) {
        console.log('call validation: ', args)
        new SimpleSchema({
            title: { type: String },
            filename: { type: String },
        }).validate(args)
    },

    // Factor out Method body so that it can be called independently (3)
    run({ filename, title }) {
        let inserted_object = { title, filename }
        mediaFiles.insert(inserted_object)
        return inserted_object // object of interest
    },

    call(args, callback) {
        console.log('call call method: ', args)
        const options = {
            returnStubValue: true,     // (5)
            throwStubExceptions: true  // (6)
        }
        Meteor.apply(this.name, [args], options, callback);
    }
};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        // Actually register defined method with Meteor's DDP system
        [method_InsertFile.name]: function (args) {
            method_InsertFile.validate.call(this, args);
            method_InsertFile.run.call(this, args);
        },
    });   
}
```

The method is being called as shown below

```
import { method_InsertFile } from '../api/files.collection';

method_InsertFile.call(data, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log("Return err ", err)
    else {
        console.log('result: ', res)
    }
})
```

I want to retrieve the object `inserted_object` at the end of the method call. I have tried returning a promise from within the `call` block of the method definition like this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meteor.apply(this.name, [args], options, (err, res) => {
        resolve(res)
    });
})
```

but `result` returns `undefined`.

Any pointers as to whether this is possible and how to accomplish it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is the function declared in your `Meteor.methods` that must return something so that this something is passed as result to your method call callback.

In your case, you would simply return the result of your `run` call.

In your method call, you correctly use `Meteor.apply` which executes the function with same name declared in `Meteor.methods`, and use the returned value as result for the callback.

Comment: I'll take a look at this and get back to you. Thanks